# Proof that $\sum 2^{-n\alpha} \cos(2^n x)$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is not differentiable in $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n\alpha} \cos(2^n x)$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is not differentiable in $0$.

I need to prove that the limit

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f_\alpha(h)-f_\alpha(0)}{h}$$

doesn't always exist for $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

So I guess I need to find a series $x_k\to0$ such that

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f_\alpha(x_k)-f_\alpha(0)}{x_k}=\pm\infty.$$

We have

$$\frac{f_\alpha(h)-f_\alpha(0)}{h}
=\frac{\sum_n 2^{-n\alpha} (\cos(2^n h)-1)}{h},$$

and I want the sequence

$$\frac{f_\alpha(x_k)-f_\alpha(0)}{x_k}$$

to diverge for $k\to\infty$.

But I'm confused about the two indices $k$ of the sequence and $n$ of the infinite series. I guess I have to twist it in a way that we are left with only one index, but I don't see how. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: You want $\lim_{\color{red}{k\to \infty}} \frac{f_\alpha(x_k) - f_\alpha(0)}{x_k}$ not $k\to 0$ ($x_k \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$). Related question: [(a Version of) Weierstrass' Function Is Nowhere Differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122999/beginning-to-prove-that-a-version-of-weierstrass-function-is-nowhere-differen?rq=1)

Comment: From that source: $g(x_m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}h\left(\frac{2^n}{2^m}\right)=\frac{1}{2^m}(m+1)$. I'm having trouble finding a similar relation in my case. I guess I have to throw $\pi$ in there somewhere and see what happens.

Comment: Okay. Applying that idea to my case, $x_k=2^{-k}\pi$ would be a similar choice. But then again, I don't see how I can get rid of the infinite sum so easily.

Comment: Something like that should work. You can evaluate part of the sum ($\sum_{n=k}^\infty$) exactly and the rest you probably need to estimate. Note that you only need to show that $|f(x_k) - f(0)|$ doesn't go to zero.

Comment: In the end, it wasn't that hard. I can choose $x_k = 2^{-k} \pi$ and estimate the sum because for $k\neq n$ the summands only take negative values. Hence I'm left with $k=n$ and everything comes out nicely so it's obvious that the difference quotient goes to $-\infty$.